# Fluid grid is not scaling correctly

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout, grid-layout, fluid-images

I have this fluid grid with a `max-width` of 1280px.

It consists of five column setup - grid2, grid4, grid6, grid8 and grid10.

Overall and at first glance it looks good, but when inspecting the code (inspected in firefox and google chrome) the smallest spot (grid2) is one pixel smaller in height.

At `max-width` the height should be 320px as the rest of the spots, but it is only 319px.

I cant get this working properly.

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ya94/

```
.grid2 {
    width: 18.72%;
}
```

I hope any of you can help \O/

Answer (score 0):

This is due to subpixel rendering.

Your defined `div`s width is `1280px * 18.72%;` which is `239.616px`

The width/height ratio is `240px / 320px = 0.75`

So the height will be `239.616px / 0.75 = 319.488px` which is then rounded down to `319px`

For your ref: Per CSS 2.1 Specification in section [10.6.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-height)

> if 'height' has a computed value of 'auto', and the element has an
>   intrinsic ratio then the used value of 'height' is:
>
> ```
> (used width) / (intrinsic ratio)
> ```

Comment: This makes sense, so this means I should make new values to the grid sizes? Or Can this in some Way be fixed in a good Way?

Comment: Different browsers handle subpixel rendering in different ways and there's no definite solution and you need to do some research and implement the best scenario that fits your target browsers/audience.